# Angular2 material - reset form is called when not expected

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In a div, there is a form and button that resets the form.

```
<div>
   <button (click)="clearForm()">Clear Form</button>
   <form [formGroup]="personForm">
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput formControlName="id"/>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput formControlName="name"/>
      </mat-form-field>
   </form>
```

Ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.personForm = this.fb.group({
    id:['123',Validators.required],
    name:['Dave',Validators.required]
    });
 }
clearForm(){
   this.personForm.reset();
}
```

The problem is, each time one of the inputs is in focus and the user clicks the 'Enter' button in the keyboard, the "clearForm()" is being called, and so the form is being reset!

If I remove the:

```
(click)="clearForm()"
```

from the button, than all works fine.

But I need it on the button...

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 <button (click)="clearForm()" type="button">Clear Form</button>
```